# Ubicación composer.json en cake2.X

Tags: json, cakephp, composer, cakephp-bake

es que estoy en la versión 2.x de cakephp pero tengo dos composer.json y no se cual es el que tengo que editar.

esta este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como pueden ver ese esta fuera de la carpeta app

y esta este otro:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y como pueden ver esta se encuentra adentro de la carpeta app, hasta ahora es donde he metido las librerías que he instalado con el composer, pero no se si están bn ubicadas

Answer (score 1):

Justo estoy haciendo un upgrade de 1.x a 2.x y quise instalar DebugKit usando composer. Al parecer el que esta dentro de app es para instalar Plugins y el que esta afuera para manejar otras librerias.

En el caso de DebugKit tiene pre-configurado instalarse en el folder Plugin, si lo ejecutas desde fuera de app crea un folder Plugin, cuando deberia instalarse en el Folder Plugin dentro de app.

Espero esto te ayude.